# Log the 'Application Force Close' Details on android phone

Tags: android, logging

I want to log some details when the Application gets force close itself.

Ya, the best way is to actually check/test all cases to not let app get force close. But for a big application, there always arise some rare cases(I even get force close sometimes on native google maps/facebook application of my phone).

So I would like to get some details related to force close of my application(best case would be the details i get when i run app in emulator in eclipse) and store it in DB/Somewhere, so that i can later on send it to my server (whenever app is started again) to track/look upon.

What would be the approach for logging such information ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [link](http://code.google.com/p/acra/). It is an API that enables you to send error logs to your account or server.

Comment: Thank,, but is there any way i can handle the Force close by myself on the application... calling a thread or something to process info that i want...